# How do you group on 2 fields on an associated schema in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here are my 2 schemas:

I have a bunch of recipes assigned to different days of the week, and each recipe contains ingredients, which consists of the ingredientObject, quantity, and unit.

I'd like to figure out where date is between values 20190008 and 20190010, the sum of quantity grouped by ingredientObject and unit.

I don't think I need to populate the ingredientObject, but I think the solution involves populating recipes, and them somehow being able to group on fields on the associated object. I've done a bunch of searching but am at a loss on how to do this. I could do this easily in SQL but Mongo / Mongoose is throwing me for a loop. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
var daySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 date: DateOnly,
 day: Number,
 recipes: [
  {
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: "Recipe"
  }
 ],
 usedBy: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: "User"
 }
});

var recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
tag: [String],
createdBy: {
 type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 ref: "User"
},
usedBy: [{
 type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 ref: "User"
}],
ingredients: [{
 ingredientObject: ingredientObjectSchema,
 quantity: {type: Number, default: 1},
 unit: {type: String, default: 'unit'}
}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick

```
Day.aggregate([
  // first you need to find days which are between 20190008 and 20190010
  {
    $match: {
      '$and': [{ 'date': { $gte: 20190008 } }, { 'date': { $lte: 20190010 } }]
    }
  },
  // now get recipes from the recipes table according to the ids in the recipes key
  {
    $lookup:
    {
      from: 'recipes', // apparently mongoose pluralises the table names
      localField: 'recipes',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'recipes_data'
    }
  },
  // All the recipes are stored in the recipes_data object, but they are arrays instead of simple objects, so we'll unwind them
  {
    $unwind: '$recipes_data'
  },
  // Again since ingredients is an array, we'll unwind that as well and make individual objects as each document
  {
    $unwind: '$recipes_data.ingredients'
  },
  // Now we can group by ingredientObject and unit
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { "ingredientObject": "$recipes_data.ingredients.ingredientObject", "unit": "$recipes_data.ingredients.unit" },
      quantity: { $sum: "$recipes_data.ingredients.quantity" }
    }
  },
]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much - your comments were super helpful in explaining how to think through this kind of query. I had to make a few tweaks to get this to work:  

1. We wanted to search on the date field which was defined as a Number (it's simply how the DateOnly package works), so $match needed to be updated to
    'date': {$gte: 2019008}, etc.
  
2. mongoose automatically pluralizes collection names, so it needed to be 
    $lookup: { from: 'recipes',

Comment: 3. ingredients is actually an array in recipes_data, so the second unwind needed to be:   
    $unwind: '$recipes_data.ingredients' 
with similar updates where I appended $recipes_data to the fields specified in $group

Comment: Glad I could help, btw I didn't run the aggregations myself. I'll make the changes you mentioned in the answer, so that anyone else reading the answer will not make the same mistakes